# if $n^2<a<b<c<d<(n+1)^2$ ,then prove $ad\neq bc$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> There are different a number of natural numbers $a,b,c,d$,there such 
>   $$n^2<a<b<c<d<(n+1)^2$$
>   show that:

$$ad\neq bc$$

This problem is from this PDF (page 9,and the second problem): see 
[link](http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=ya2YmCgraiJne9uLwakw5NA3Sqp2NRek6MIra2E2E2DvTT123txfh8hisNjQeXdWb0lTQBVRe4mnE6ACUjzQrgke4_Je9iqR9t4c7p6orEi)

My idea: Assume that there exist natural numbers $a,b,c,d$ such 
$$ad=bc$$
then I can't  have contradiction

Thank you

Comment: More simply put: Suppose $n^2 < a < b < c < d < (n+1)^2$. Show that $ad \ne bc$.

Comment: $ac\ne bd$ as in the problem statement is trivial. You want $ad\ne bc$ (as matches your attempt at indirect proof).

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson,I have edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a purely geometric inequality. I will prove that the only couple of points in $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2: y\geq x, n^2\leq x,y\leq (n+1)^2\}$ collinear with the origin is $(n^2,n^2+n),(n^2+n,(n+1)^2)$.

Let $R_k$ be the subset of $R$ made of points for which $y-x=k>0$.

The arguments ($\arctan(y/x)$) of the elements of $R_k$ are clearly all distinct.

Now I claim that the argument of the rightmost element of $R_{k+1}$ is greater than the argument of the leftmost element of $R_k$. This is equivalent to:
$$ \frac{n^2+k}{n^2} \leq \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2-(k+1)},\tag{1}$$
or just to:
$$ (n-k)^2 \geq 0,$$
with equality only when $k=n$. However, in order to have $ad-bc=0$, $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ must be two points of $R$ collinear with the origin. My previous argument now gives $b=c$, contradiction.

Comment: "The arguments (arctan(y/x)) of the elements of Rk are clearly all distinct" - you probably mean for k<>0?

Comment: "This is equivalent to: ...": Isn't the equivalence true only when $k>0$? (since the $y$ coordinate of the rightmost element is $(n+1)^2$)

Comment: +1.  The diagonal must obviously be left out so $x<y$ which is just fine by the conditions of the question.

Answer (score 1):

*Claim:* When $a<b<c<d$ and $ad=bc$ then there is a square $m^2$ with $a\leq m^2\leq d$.

*Proof:* Write
$$a=r u,\quad b= r v,\qquad {\rm gcd}(u,v)=1\ ,$$
ensuring $v\geq u+1$. From $ad=bc$ it then follows that $c=su$, $d=sv$ with $s\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$. Write
$$r=t r',\quad s=t s',\qquad {\rm gcd}(r',s')=1\ .$$
Then 
$$a=t r' u,\quad b=t r' v,\quad c=t s' u,\quad d= ts' v\ ;$$
and as $b<c$ we conclude that $s'>r'$. It follows that
$$d\geq t(r'+1)(u+1)\geq t r'u +2\sqrt{t}\sqrt{r' u}+1=\bigl(\sqrt{tr' u}+1\bigr)^2\ ;$$
whence $m:=\left\lceil\sqrt{t r'u}\ \right\rceil=\left\lceil\sqrt{a}\ \right\rceil$ does the job.

Comment: Oh,It's nice!+1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. It is imperfect but maybe it will lead to a solution. Define:

- $A=a-n^2-n$
- $B=b-n^2-n$
- $C=c-n^2-n$
- $D=d-n^2-n$

Then the assumption becomes:

$-n<A<B<C<D<(n+1)$

And the contradiction assumption becomes:

$AD+(A+D)(n^2+n)=BC+(B+C)(n^2+n)$

Hence: $AD<BC$ and $(A+D)>(B+C)$.

They are all integers so: $(A+D)\geq(B+C+1)$ and $AD+n^2+n\leq BC$

From the assumption: $-n^2<AD<n^2$ and  $-n^2<BC<n^2$

Hence:  $(A+D)=(B+C+1)$ and $AD+n^2+n= BC$

Here I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new video by Tim Gowers solving this problem in real time:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmEVwJ_lJ1A